# Erro com a biblioteca android.support.v7.app. Como resolver?

Tags: android, eclipse

Já procurei em todo o fórum e não achei nada que solucionasse meu problema.

Sempre quando eu crio um novo projeto pelo Eclipse, ele acusa um erro na biblioteca android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity, dentro da classe principal. O estranho é que esse erro só acontece nos novos projetos. Nos projetos antigos que já foram criados, essa biblioteca funciona normal.

Segue abaixo o meu console:

```
[2014-12-20 12:14:30 - Taskk] Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.
[2014-12-20 12:14:56 - Taskk] Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.
[2014-12-20 12:15:14 - Contactos] Unable to resolve target 'android-8'
[2014-12-20 12:21:37 - Beer] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2014-12-20 12:21:37 - Beer] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2014-12-20 12:21:37 - Beer] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2014-12-20 12:21:37 - Beer] Versions found are:
[2014-12-20 12:21:37 - Beer] Path: C:\Users\PC\Documents\Estudy\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-12-20 12:21:37 - Beer]    Length: 758727
[2014-12-20 12:21:37 - Beer]    SHA-1: efec67655f6db90757faa37201efcee2a9ec3507
[2014-12-20 12:21:37 - Beer] Path: C:\Users\PC\Documents\Estudy\Project1\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2014-12-20 12:21:37 - Beer]    Length: 995624
[2014-12-20 12:21:37 - Beer]    SHA-1: 3e4e879d0b3dc11f2feb3f55e77e3b5bd82c4a28
[2014-12-20 12:21:37 - Beer] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencie
```

Já passei dias tentando descobrir o porquê desse erro.

Comment: Na verdade o erro está dizendo que há versões diferentes da mesma biblioteca (`android-support-v4.jar`) rodando. Veja se removendo esse .jar da pasta libs do seu projeto lhe ajuda.

Comment: @Thomas Eu fui na pasta do meu projeto e só encontrei apenas um `android-support-v4.jar`. O estranho é que não é apenas em um projeto, e sim em todos que eu crio. Já os antigos, funcionam normalmente. Tem mais alguma sugestão?

Comment: O problema é que ele está pegando o android-support-v4.jar de outro caminho **além** desse 'único' que você achou na pasta libs desse projeto. Remova-o, limpe e construa o projeto.

Comment: @Thomas Consegui!! Obrigado mesmo pela ajuda. Eu consegui da seguinte maneira: Fui até o diretório onde estava TODOS os meus projetos, ex: `Documents\Study\appcompat_v7\libs` e removi o `android-support-v4.jar`. Eu estava indo no diretório do meu próprio projeto e excluindo. Por isso não adiantava. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @sTokes, cuidado ao remover... Porque se o **appcompat v7** tem essa lib, é porque ele garante que tudo que ele tem funciona nessa versão (tudo que foi feito foi testado nessa versão). Eu recomendo você a pegar essa lib do **appcompat** e use-a nos seus projetos.

Comment: @Wakim Não entendi muito bem. Então quando eu for criar um novo projeto, eu devo copiar o `android-suppot-v4.jar` para a libs do meu projeto? O mais estranho é que esse problema começou quando eu fiz uma pequena atualização. Então, mesmo excluindo essa lib do **appcompat v7**, pode haver erros no futuro? É uma maneira errada?

Comment: Na verdade, esse erro é porque as duas lib's (a do **appcompat** e as dos seus projetos) estão com versões diferentes (hash's diferentes). Se você colocar todas as lib's na mesma versão, o erro não vai mais acontecer. Preciso confirmar, mas acredito que foi a atualização quem causou este erro, pois quando atualizou as versões ficaram diferentes.

Comment: @Wakim Obrigado pela explicação! Entendi. Então, existe alguma forma de "desfazer" essa atualização? Eu tenho projetos importantes que já estão quase prontos, estou com um medo de bugar alguma coisa na pasta deles. Tem alguma ideia de como eu posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Chegou a tentar copiar o jar do **support v4** do **appcompat** para os seus projetos? O inverso do que fez anteriormente. Chegou a dar algum problema?

Comment: @Wakim Na verdade, quando eu crio algum projeto, o **support v4** é criado automaticamente dentro da pasta libs do projeto. É realmente necessário copiar e substitui-lo?